# Из json в dataframe: извлечение значений второго уровня

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Есть json-файл, который мне нужно оформить в датафрейм, однако из-за вложенных значений второго уровня (если правильно объясняю), все сливается в одну строку. Сам файл здесь: https://pastebin.com/JXD971Ue

На выходе хочется получить фрейм формата **source_type - date - organic - paid**

Пробовала сделать вот так:

```
result = json.loads(response.text)
first_res = pd.DataFrame(result.get('visits'))
```

Но это закономерно не сработало тут. Получается вот такое:[image: такое]

Help, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [pd.json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

```
res = pd.json_normalize(data["visits"]["site.ru"], ["visits"], ["source_type"])
```

---

результат:

```
In [64]: res
Out[64]:
         date      organic          paid  source_type
0  2020-03-01  6530.145805  11560.472063       Search
1  2020-03-01   920.343435      0.000000       Social
2  2020-03-01   280.145453      0.000000         Mail
3  2020-03-01     0.000000  53484.768980  Display Ads
4  2020-03-01  2759.261341      0.000000       Direct
5  2020-03-01  1580.916180      0.000000    Referrals
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!